# How to progress game to next level

Tags: java, arrays, static-variables

For my project I am designing a game that has three levels, each set out as an array. Upon completing each level, the game should automatically progress to the next level. I currently have it progressing from the 1st to 2nd level, but upon completing level 2, it simply reloads levels 2 again. My teacher says I should be using a variable to determine my current level, and incrementing it as I progress to the next level, which I am doing, so I'm unsure of why the game is stuck on level 2. He mentioned I should be using a static variable but I don't understand how that differs from what I'm doing currently.

````
{
    private char[][] level1 = {
        {'#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', '|', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', '@', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', ' ', '$', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}
    };
    
    private char[][] level2 = {
        {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', '@', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', '$', '$', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#'},
        {'#', ' ', '$', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '|', '#'},
        {'#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '|', '#'},
        {' ', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', '#'},
        {' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#'},
        {' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#'},
        {' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    };
    
    private char[][] level3 = {
        {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', '#', '@', ' ', '#', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', '$', '*', ' ', '#', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', '|', '*', ' ', '#', ' '},
        {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' '},
        {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' '},
    };

public void act() {
\\game code here

if (testLevelComplete() == true) {
            levelComplete();   
        }
        
    }
   
    
    public void levelComplete()
    {
        int currentLevel = 0;
        currentLevel = currentLevel + 1;
        showWarning("Level Complete! Current level is " + currentLevel);
        if (currentLevel == 1) {
            loadLevel(level1);
        } else {
        if (currentLevel == 2) {
            loadLevel(level2);
        } else {
         if (currentLevel == 3) {
            loadLevel(level3);
        } else {
        if (currentLevel > 3) {
            showWarning("Level Complete! No more levels.");
        }}}}
        
        
    }
    
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking for the next level, you are restarting to 0, then re-add 1 because the `currentLevel` variable is include in method.

I suggest you to do something like that :

```java
private int currentLevel = 0; // make the variable global
// to update always the same and not restarting all time

public void levelComplete() { // your method
   currentLevel++; // go to next level
   showWarning("Level Complete! Current level is " + currentLevel);
   if (currentLevel == 1) { // set lvl1
       loadLevel(level1);
   } else if (currentLevel == 2) { // set lvl2
       loadLevel(level2);
   } else if (currentLevel == 3) { // set lvl3
       loadLevel(level3);
   } else if (currentLevel > 3) { // completed
       showWarning("Level Complete! No more levels.");
   }
}
```

Also, instead of doing `else { if(...) }` prefer use `else if(...)`

Comment: I tried this piece of code and still couldn't get it to work. It still doesn't increment past 1.

Comment: What do you mean with "past 1" ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the levelComplete method, the variable currentLevel will be assign to 0 again.
If you want to keep the variable state, you should set the currentLevel variable as the member variable of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Like in most main-stream programming languages, variables are *scoped* in Java.
Usually the curly braces `{` start or end a scope.

```
public void levelComplete()
{
    int currentLevel = 0; // starts living here
    // ... your code ...
} // `currentLevel` dies here and is gone
```

So every time you call `levelComplete`, you start at zero.

Since the level is part of you game state, you should move it up to be a property of your Game Object. These properties live as long as your object does, e.g.:

```
public class Game {
    // Lives as long as the containing Game object does
    private int level = 0;

    public void levelComplete() // shouldn't this rather be private?
    {
        this.level++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this piece of code and still couldn't get it to work. It still doesn't increment past 1.

Comment: Please update your question with your current code (try to keep it short). Otherwise I don't know what is going wrong.